# Error while Dual Booting Ubuntu with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, live-usb, bios, grub-legacy

I've almost gone through every piece of article there is on Dual booting Ubuntu. And still cannot find solution to my problem. I hope someone here can help me.

What I have done:

1. Found out that my Partition Style is GPT from properties of my Disk 0.
2. Shrunk up my C-Drive and free up 90GB for Ubuntu.
3. Created my bootable drive using Rufus with GPT selected (Read somewhere that both USB and Disk0 should be same)..
4. Restarted my laptop, ***F10/BIOS Setup*** --> ***Login as Guest/YES*** --> ***Advanced*** --> ***Boot Options***. Wanted to change Boot Mode to EFI (Read somewhere that should disable legacy and boot from EFI) but the only three option I had were: Legacy, UEFI Hybrid & UEFI Native.
5. Tried all three choices one by one but NO option would let me Live-Boot from my USB.

Error: No Operating System found on disk(Maybe be because of GPT).

These are my Advanced Tab options in BIOS Setup. What Changes should I make?
Or Is there any other problem?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ofdb.jpg

My Laptop is HP ProBook 440 G1 and Ubuntu 16.04

Please Let me know if you need other details.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is the right screen : https://i.imgur.com/XxooZ10.jpg but you messed it up. "usb" is ssupposed to be before "OS Boot Manager" it's one of the F* keys to move items up and down. try them all. once you have "usb" first, click "save" and then exit out of there. on the next reboot (granted you've plugged in the USB) it should boot to it. you can also boot to your usb from windows 10, using advanced startup https://i.pinimg.com/originals/30/1b/4f/301b4fead718c79c75928876651f7bbd.jpg

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to newest from HP? Many with HP have said UEFI updates have resolved a variety of HP related issues. May also be better to use 18.04 as it newer kernel & drivers, so more updates than 16.04.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @tatsu I moved USB on top and it worked and I installed it perfectly but now when I start my Laptop it automatically boots into windows without giving me the window to choose Ubuntu from. I tried writing 'bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi' into admin CMD but it didn't work.

Comment: @oldfred My UEFI/BIOS is at it's latest version. I'm using 16.04 because I'm working for my college project and our guide need this version. Thanks

Comment: @tatsu How do I do that? My UEFI Boot order is the same in my above image and there isn't anywhere else in whole BIOS where I can find Boot order with Ubuntu in it. My BIOS is different from yours. :-( Please Help

Comment: @tatsu Give me few mins, I'll check it and get back. OS Choosing menu appeared the first time after installing ubuntu but never again.

Comment: Do not understand why college would require version that may not work on your system. Often newer drivers are required. Some of the older work arounds for HP systems. You may be able to boot the fallback or hard drive entry which is at /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @tatsu I did what you told me to do, this is it https://imgur.com/a/AGZw5Sq And now this screen pops up before booting windows https://imgur.com/a/2WAAxAw Didn't work

Comment: @oldfred This looks tough, I'll read and understand your link and try it out. I'll tell you later if it worked.

Comment: @tatsu He want's it because We'll be learning ROS and ROS Kinetic need 16.04 to run not newer. :-(    Is there anything else I can do to solve this?

Comment: @tatsu That's a lot of installation! Damn Using Ubuntu is not easy

Comment: here's ros2 https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Install-Debians/ should be just the same and these are instructions for installing on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @tatsu I'm talking about me, it's not easy running dual boot because I cannot figure what do I do? Nothing is working for me. Thanks for your help btw, really appreciate it.

Comment: I have seen that error message before. Probably on HP as it does not correctly follow UEFI standards. But you should not have /EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi, it should be /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi or /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi. But since it seems to want that, you can just copy grubx64.efi from /ubuntu to /boot folder in EFI folder. Not sure if that will work or not.